# Owncloud App Routing

Tags: symfony, owncloud

Hello i have an app that added to my owncloud projet and i would like to perform in action like : php occ files:scan

So i created a new button on my app (view part) :

```
<button><a href="<?php p(\OC::$server->getURLGenerator()->linkToRoute('lotsofusers.page.scan' , ['uid' => $_['username']] )); ?>"><?php p($l->t('Scanner les fichiers utilisateur')); ?></a></button>
```

I create a new route in my routes.php file :

```
['verb' => 'GET',  'name' => 'page#scan', 'url' => '/users/{uid}'],
```

And then i created my controller :

```
/**
     * Returns scanfiles for a user
     * @NoAdminRequired
     * @param  string $username Username
     * @return page
     */
    public function scan($username){

        $user = $this->userManager->get($username);

        var_dum($user); 

        die;



    }
```

When i click to the button i don't go to my var_dump and breakpoint, the button generate once again the page why ? hope someone could help

Comment: Can you use twig path function ?

Comment: i'm not sure i test now

Comment: no i can't :( ...

Comment: What twig path have you tried please ?

Comment: twig seems to be not used in owncloud ! the twig language is not interpreted

Comment: The link of the route in <a href don't work ! i don't know why ..